# Implicit differentiation. Is y a function of x? What is going on?

Tags: calculus

I am a bit confused at the concept of implicit differentiation. Say we have this question:

[image]

So I guess the implication here is that y is a function of x?

Is that that why $\frac{dy}{dx}$ of $\sin{y}$ is cos(y)$\frac{dy}{dx}$? I'm a bit confused.

I guess this stems from my confusion about the difference between $\frac{dy}{dx}$ vs $\frac{d}{dx}$

When we differentiate a simple equation like $y = 2x$ and say $\frac{dy}{dx} = 2$, the implication here is that y is a function of x obviously which is why we can take the derivative of y with respect to x. Is the same thing going on when taking the derivative of $\sin{y} = x$? I feel like I'm missing something or that I'm glossing over an important concept here.

Comment: Note: This implicit differentiation is also useful when you need to find a tangent line for a relation at a given point. For example, to a circle $x^2+y^2=r^2$. You can easily derivate it: $2x+2yy'=0$, so $y'=-\frac{x}{y}$. It's much easier than getting $2$ "ugly" functions: $y(x)=\pm \sqrt{r^2-x^2}$, finding out which branch do you need and differentiating it.

Comment: "So I guess the implication here is that y is a function of x?"  y and x and dependent.  So they can be seen locally as functions of each other, yes.  I say "locally" because one value of $x$ may have many values of $y$.  But that doesn't matter for differentiating.

Comment: This is just the chain rule $\frac{d}{dx} = \frac{d}{dy}\frac{dy}{dx}$

Comment: $\sin y = x \implies \arcsin (\sin y) = \arcsin (x) \implies y \pm 2k\pi = \arcsin (x) \implies y = \arcsin x \mp 2k\pi$, so ,yes, $y$ is a function of $x$.  Although we don't actually need to figure out exactly which one.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, $y$ is a function of $x$. Strictly speaking, we are taking $\sin (y(x)) = x$, and differentiating with respect to $x$ using the chain rule to obtain $$y'(x) \cos(y(x)) = 1$$
whereupon the conclusion follows as written.

This explicit writing of $y$ as $y(x)$ is something that is often not taught at all, I'm afraid, but whenever you define $y = ax+b$, for instance, this is shorthand for defining a function $y(x) = ax+b$.

Comment: ohhhhhhhhhhhhhh

Comment: I kind of wish the notation $y(x)$ or better yet, IMO, the notation $y_x$ was taught more.

Comment: $y_x$ means something entirely different in the context of derivatives so I don't recommend that.

Answer (score 0):

The idea is that you have some values $x^*,y^*$ such that $\sin y^* = x^*$
and furthermore, $\sin' y^* \neq 0$.

I am using the $ ^*$ so I can distinguish values from functions.

If this is true, then the inverse function theorem says that there is a
local **differentiable** inverse $y$ (to $\sin$) such that (for $z$ close to $y^*$)
$y(\sin z ) = z$.

In particular, $y( \sin y^*) = y(x^*) = y^*$.

If we differentiate, we get
$y'( \sin z ) \sin' z = y'( \sin z ) \cos z = 1$ and so, setting $z=y^*$ we get
$y'(\sin y^*) = y'(x^*) = {1 \over \cos y^*}$.